# CReating unique file containing unique column line

Tags: bash

I have a input.txt file like this.

`$cat input.txt`

`a.ex.com`

`b.ex.com`

`r.mx.com`

`b.foz.cop.com`

`tr.cop.com`

And I want the output like this.

`$cat output.txt`

`ex.com`

`mx.com`

`cop.com`

`foz.cop.com`

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow (SO). May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)? Moreover, SO is not a free coding service. You are supposed to show what you tried so far, what results it produced and why it is not what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
$ cat 1.txt
a.ex.com
b.ex.com
r.mx.com
b.foz.cop.com
tr.cop.com

$ while read -r line; do echo $line|cut -f2- -d. ; done < 1.txt|uniq
ex.com
mx.com
foz.cop.com
cop.com
```